# How to sync only certain rows in a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to sync a couple of tables from a central (sql-server) database *dbA* to a local (sql-ce) client database *dbB*. To this I'm planning to use the Microsoft sync framework. And I have managed to get it working so far as to sync all the rows (or updated rows) in some specified tables.

However, my *dbA* contains very much data, and it is also growing, so I don't want the customers to have a full copy of the *dbA* in their local databases. Instead I just want them to have some parts of the database (some rows that depends on some expression, for instance from *tableA* just select rows where *moduleId = 4*)

So initially I thought that *filters* seemed to be the thing for me. Specifically *parameter based filters* where I can specify a parameter to the filter. However after some investigation it appears that when creating a parameter based filter, you are actually just creating a template, and then creating different scopes from that.

I can't describe exactly what my application does, but you could think of it almost as a version handling system, and the parameter would represent what version I want to select from. So you can see that it would become a large number of scopes.

So in the end, what are my options?

Comment: Have you looked at SQL Server Merge Replication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you maybe use a SQL function for the filter-parameter so this can change?

Something like

```
serverTemplate.Tables["tableA"].AddFilterColumn("ModuleId");
serverTemplate.Tables["tableA"].FilterClause = "[side].[ModuleId] = sf_GetCurrentModule()";
```

You could create a SQL function sf_GetCurrentModule() to return the ModuleId to be synched. If the rows to be synched vary from client to client, you would at least need a synch scope per client - which is not a problem, just use an unique name for the scope, and maybe pass an id from the client to the function:

```
serverTemplate.Tables["tableA"].FilterClause = string.Format("[side].[ModuleId] = sf_GetCurrentModule({0})", ClientId);
```

So you could return the ModuleId to be synched depending on the client.

Hope this helps.

Travis

Comment: Yes thanks Travis. This is actually what I'm doing right now. The problem with this is that in my application the user adds more modules as time goes. And while syncing the second module, all the tracking tables are removed from the local database... so the sync will download and append all the needed data again (even if some of the data is the same as in the first module). And that was exactly what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: However since this wasn't mentioned in my question I will mark your answer as the answer.
Another thing that I didn't mention is that the sync is only download (no upload will ever be done)